# java.io.FileNotFoundException. Проблема с запуском программы через cmd

Tags: intellij-idea, cmd

Написала программу, запускаю в IntellijIdea - все работает. Через командную строку не получается, не может найти текстовый файл. Вот код: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Сначала было так:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Р?Р?Р?РєС?Р°Р?Р?С?Р°\IdeaProjects\test1\out\production\test1\text.txt (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Field.loadFieldFromFile(Field.java:46)
    at Field.<init>(Field.java:12)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:5)
```

Я подумала, что может быть проблема в кодировке, и сменила кодировку в командной строке в UTF-8 (chcp 65001), чтобы была как в intellijIdea. Теперь шапка поменялась, но все еще исключение выскакивает:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Александра\IdeaProjects\test1\out\production\test1\text.txt (     )
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: А `path`-то как получается и чему равно?

Comment: Устанавливаю значение path в конструкторе Field, а при создании filed передаю аргумент конструктору C:\\...

Comment: "C:\\..." - это что значит?

Comment: Начнём с того, уверены ли Вы в том, что файл там действительно есть на момент запуска?

Comment: "C:\\Users\\Александра\\IdeaProjects\\test1\\out\\production\\test1\\text" @Igor

Comment: Есть пять файлов: один текстовый, два IntellijIdea, два их класса(MainClass, Field) @Kir_Antipov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить кириллицу на путь, состоящий только из латинских букв. Скорее всего, проблема заключается именно в этом.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Так, вы хотите сказать, поменять имя юзера? Или еще раз сменить кодировку?

Comment: Я поняла, менять имя юзера не хотелось, я закинула в папку Users и путь сменился на C:\Users\test1\src. Скомпилировала снова, поменяв путь в main на новый. Теперь работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте кодировку проекта по умолчанию на UTF-8 иначе со всеми русскими символами далее будут проблемы. Делается это здесь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]